# What is the difference between these ways of attaching events?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

1. `<div id="myDiv" onclick="MyFunc()"></div>`
2. `document.getElementById("myDiv").onclick = MyFunc;`
3. `document.getElementById("myDiv").addEventListener("click", MyFunc, false)`

Now, what is the difference between these 3 ways of attaching an event to a DOM element (ignoring the fact that 3 won't work on IE)?

Comment: They all call `MyFunc` on click. Difference in terms of what?

Comment: IE doesn't like `addEventListener` but it works with [`attachEvent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536343(v=vs.85).aspx) instead

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6348597/219118) provides a pretty good explanation. Really there is no difference though.. all do the same thing.

Comment: using addeventlistner "this" varible inside MYFunc function  will always refer to calling object which is myDiv  instead of window object if you simply write onclick() event in plain html

Comment: possible duplicate of [addeventhandler vs onclick](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6348494/addeventhandler-vs-onclick)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Methods A and B**

These are known as DOM level zero events and are somewhat old school. Method A declares it in-line in your HTML (bad) where as method B does the same thing but centrally, in your JS.

With method A, the attribute value is a string of valid JS that, on firing, will be evaluated (also bad). Due to the position in which the event is being bound, this means any functions referenced in this string must be global (or globally accessible methods). With method B, the event is bound centrally, in your JS, rather than inline.

The main caveat with them, aside from being outdated and simplified, is that you can bind only one kind of event per element. If you attempt to bind two click event handlers to the same event handler with this mechanism, the first will be forgotten. This stands to reason, since you are simply overwriting an element attribute.

**Method C**

`addEventListener` is the standard for attaching events. For a long time, IE didn't support this, favouring its equivalent `attachEvent` method. Some differences between them include:

- `attachEvent` does not allow capturing of events (param 3 of `addEventListener` allows this)
- with `attachEvent`, the event object (i.e. the object that stores information about the fired event) is accessed on `window.event`, whereas with `addEventListener` it is forwarded as the only argument to the callback
- with `attachEvent`, event names must be prefixed with `on`, e.g. `onClick`. `addEventListener` requires simply `click`
- with `addEventListener`, the `this` keyword inside the callback points to the element that triggered the event. In `attachEvent` you have to decipher this yourself by extrating the element from properties within the event (`window.event`) object

IE9 came into line and supports `addEventListener`.

Comment: A and B are _not_ the same thing - A requires that the passed string be converted into a real function into `eval` and any function call therein must be in the global scope, whereas B can use any real direct function reference, even if it's in some restricted scope.

Comment: @Alnitak - you are right; I was simply referring to the fact that both are simply different means of attaching DOM 0 events. Editing...